# Excel: Sum Up quantity values from column B if the names from Column A are duplicates and also if Column A is found in Column C

Tags: excel

I have three columns: A = Name , B = Quantity and C= Name in different order , also some names from A are duplicates but the quantity from duplicates are different.

How can I get the sum of quantitys (B) if A=names and duplicate A is found in C???

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the formula `=SUMIF(A:A,C2,B:B)' in D2 and then copy down